# how to manage uipanels matlab gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have 6 uipanels ,all same size overlapped one over another. I have to add buttons edit text to all the uipanels.but I can edit only 6th uipanel and all others are hidden.how can I make only one uipanel visible at a time so that I can easily add buttons and text to it. I have to add a push button in each panel which when clicked should show succeeding uipanel and hide previous uipanel.

For example,
I have a uipanel1 with a push button.when. I click the push button,it should show uipanel2 and hide uipanel1.
thanks

Comment: what have u done so far?

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are after. That should be pretty much how you choose to design it I think. However, my guess is that you are looking for the function [`uistack`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html). There is also an option whether or not a UI component will be visible. Try for example the simplest case here. `h=figure; get(h)`. You will see a parameter called `Visible` which, differently than Java, has default `'on'`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to define yours uipanels as variables. For example, uipanel1 = uipanel(...); uipanel2 = uipanel(...)
So you can access easily to your six uipanel handles and put these handles in your button callback function.

Another solution would be to use the 'Tag' property for the uipanel in order to identify the uipanel. It may be longer but by using the findobj('Tag','uipanel1_tag') function, you can easily find the desired handle.